# Apps Script not accessing through Flutter App APK

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-apps-script

I have followed these steps.

1. I first wrote an App Script.
2. Then I did Publish > Deploy as WebApp.. > Anyone has access
3. Using the Current Web App URL in the flutter app, which works fine during development.
4. Made an APK of the app using **flutter build apk** command
5. Installed app-release.apk
6. It is not fetching any data from the deployed WebApp, seems anyone access not working, but that URL is working everywhere else, even in postman an incognito. And even this web app URL is working during development. ***Why not in the APK?***

Comment: check if internet permissions are specified before building the apk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that I forgot to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

in my AppManifest.xml located in android/app/src/main.